# Address for an EEA family permit

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, uk-visa, eu-spouses

I am a Polish citizen. My husband is Egyptian. We live together in Egypt. I have never been to the UK.

We are refilling application on the visa4uk website and one of the questions made us a bit confused.

> Is the UK address given the permanent address of the EEA National?

We chose option 'no'  because I don't have a permanent address in the UK. I had to put another address.

What address we should put here?

1. The address where we are currently living in Egypt (Address mentioned in our marriage certificate).
2. The address from Poland as I am still registered there as a permanent resident (although I left 9 months ago).

Comment: I don't think it matters much, but I suspect that you should give the address in Egypt if you intend to reside there indefinitely.  The fact that you haven't de-registered from your Polish address would likely be seen as an administrative formality that doesn't have a bearing on your actual "permanent address."